# Oracle pipelined function cannot access remote table (ORA-12840) when used in a union

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a pipelined function which returns a table. I use this function like a dynamic view in another function, in a `with` clause, to mark certain records. I then use the results from this query in an aggregate query, based on various criteria. What I want to do is `union all` these aggregations together (as they all use the same source data, but show aggregations at different heirarchical levels).

When I produce the data for individual levels, it works fine. However, when I try to combine them, I get an ORA-12840 error: `cannot access a remote table after parallel/insert direct load txn`.

(I should note that my function and queries are looking at tables on a remote server, via a DB link).

Any ideas what's going on here?

---

Here's an idea of the code:

```
function getMatches(criteria in varchar2) return myTableType pipelined;
```

...where this function basically executes some dynamic SQL, which references remote tables, as a reference cursor and spits out the results.

Then the factored queries go something like:

```
with marked as (
  select id from table(getMatches('OK'))
),
fullStats as (
  select    mainTable.id,
            avg(nvl2(marked.id, 1, 0)) isMarked,
            sum(mainTable.val) total
  from      mainTable
  left join marked
  on        marked.id = mainTable.id
  group by  mainTable.id
)
```

The reason for the first factor is speed -- if I inline it, in the join, the query goes really slowly -- but either way, it doesn't alter the status of whatever's causing the exception.

Then, say for a complete overview, I would do:

```
select sum(total) grandTotal
from   fullStats
```

...or for an overview by `isMarked`:

```
select sum(total) grandTotal
from   fullStats
where  isMarked = 1
```

These work fine individually (my pseudocode maybe wrong or overly simplistic, but you get the idea), but as soon as I `union all` them together, I get the ORA-12840 error :(

---

**EDIT** By request, here is an obfuscated version of my function:

```
function getMatches(
    search in varchar2)
  return idTable pipelined
  as
    idRegex     varchar2(20) := '(05|10|20|32)\d{3}';
    searchSQL   varchar2(32767);

    type rc is ref cursor;
    cCluster rc;
    rCluster idTrinity;

    BAD_CLUSTER exception;
  begin
    if regexp_like(search, '^L\d{3}$') then
      searchSQL := 'select distinct null id1, id2_link id2, id3_link id3 from anotherSchema.linkTable@my.remote.link where id2 = ''' || search || '''';    
    elsif regexp_like(search, '^' || idRegex || '(,' || idRegex || || ')*$') then
      searchSQL := 'select distinct null id1, id2, id3 from anotherSchema.idTable@my.remote.link where id2 in (' || regexp_replace(search, '(\d{5})', '''\1''') || ')';
    else
      raise BAD_CLUSTER;
    end if;

    open cCluster for searchSQL;
    loop
      fetch cCluster into rCluster;
      exit when cCluster%NOTFOUND;

      pipe row(rCluster);
    end loop;

    close cCluster;
    return;

  exception
    when BAD_CLUSTER then
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Invalid Cluster Search');
      return;
    when others then
      raise_application_error(-20999, 'API' || sqlcode || chr(10) || sqlerrm);
      return;
  end getMatches;
```

It's very simple, designed for an API with limited access to the database, in terms of sophistication (hence passing a comma delimited string as a possible valid argument): If you supply a grouping code, it returns linked IDs (it's a composite, 3-field key); however, if you supply a custom list of codes, it just returns those instead.

I'm on Oracle 10gR2; not sure which version exactly, but I can look it up when I'm back in the office :P

Comment: @tbone Yes; no DML is going on, which what Googling suggests this error relates to.

Comment: @Xophmeister:what is the dynamic code into the pipelined function?

Comment: just a guess, but is it possible the UNION is writing to temp and trying to do a direct path read on TEMP?

Comment: @GauravSoni Function listing provided: I may just make it non-pipelined, as per Alexander Tokarev's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest no idea where the issue came from but the simplest way to solve it - create a temporary table and populate it by values from your pipelined function and use the table inside WITH clause. Surely the temp table should be created but I'm pretty sure you get serious performance shift because dynamic sampling isn't applied to pipelined functions without tricks.

p.s. the issue could be fixed by with marked as ( select /*+ INLINE */ id from table(getMatches('OK'))) but surely it isn't the stuff you're looking for so my suggestion is confirmed WITH does something like 'insert /*+ APPEND*/' inside it'.

Comment: Do you think de-pipelining the function would have the same effect?

Comment: At least it permits to get rid of the strange error and get performance boost

Comment: Regarding you materialize pipelined results I think it is no mater whether do you de-pipeline it. As for me pipelined functions are useful either for API-related stuff or hard etl stuff that really requires hard paralleled processing...

Comment: I investigated it - unfortunately it is platform-depended issue. I suspect it happens because 'with' clause creates implicit the table in TEMP segment and it looks like it uses kind of direct path insert that sometimes doesn't work properly in distributed transaction environment - it is your case due the dblink.

Comment: If we have a look into asktom we could find:scott@ORA817DEV> !oerr ora 12840
12840, 00000, "cannot access a remote table after parallel/insert direct load txn"
// *Cause: Within a transaction, an attempt was made to perform distributed
// access after a PDML or insert direct statement had been issued.
// *Action: Commit/rollback the PDML transaction first, and then perform
// the distributed access, or perform the distributed access before the
// first PDML statement in the transaction.

Comment: The function doesn't return many results, so there's no need for it to be pipelined: I'll make that change tomorrow... Fingers crossed :)

Comment: (Original function listing added as edit, for what it's worth.)

Comment: I changed my function so that it returns a collection ([as per this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html)), but I still get the same error. Looks like using a temporary table is my only solution!

Comment: I have a stupid idea - regarding you are in the distributed transaction it could requires commit statement. Let's try to execute getMatches in autonomus transaction and before return; issue a commit statement.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderTokarev: I did fix the issue by making the function return a collection -- non-pipelined -- then assigning that to a variable in a central function. Passing this around, rather than putting it directly into SQL queries seems to have worked and, as you suggest, it's pretty quick. I couldn't use a temporary (physical) table as it causes ORA-14552 exceptions (I'm not familiar with autonomous transactions)... Anyway, on the whole: Accepted :)